# If there is no need to response in remote form how to handle it on Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render

If there is no need to response in remote form how to handle it?

the error is

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template carts/search_book_by_sn, application/search_book_by_sn with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in:
```

The code in my controller.
Because  the

> if session[:loaded_books].include? @book.id

is a  condition for false-result, so I don't want to execute any Javascript. Just keep it as same as origin

```
respond_to do |format|
  # format.js

  if session[:loaded_books].include? @book.id
    format.js
  else
    ap("Add into Array")
    session[:loaded_books] << @book.id
    ap(session[:loaded_books])

    format.js { render :action => 'add_to_cart'}

  end

end
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to send any response or render any view then the write in action

```
render :nothing => true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
respond_to do |format|
  # format.js

  if session[:loaded_books].include? @book.id
    format.js {render :nothing => true } # this might help
  else
    ap("Add into Array")
    session[:loaded_books] << @book.id
    ap(session[:loaded_books])

    format.js { render :action => 'add_to_cart'}

  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

simply do render :nothing => true in your controller